# Compare two unequal size numpy arrays and fill the exclusion elements with nan

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to do an element-by-element match of a 6x3 array with a 2x2 array. Return the bigger array with a True or False in the corresponding elements based on a match or no match. For the elements in the bigger array that cannot be compared e.g. column 3 and rows 3 to 6, I need to fill with NaN.

Here's my pseudo code:

```
first_arr_rows, first_arr_cols = 6, 3  # This is an example and will be dynamically initialized
sec_arr_rows, sec_arr_cols = 2, 2      # This is an example and will be dynamically initialized
if (sec_arr_cols <= first_arr_cols) and (sec_arr_rows <= first_arr_rows):
    compared = arr1[:sec_arr_rows,:sec_arr_cols] == arr2[:sec_arr_rows,:sec_arr_cols]
# the above statement creates a 2x2 array
    new_cols = np.zeros((first_arr_rows, first_arr_cols - sec_arr_cols))
    new_rows = np.zeros((first_arr_rows - sec_arr_rows, compared.shape[1]))
    compared = np.append(compared, new_rows, axis=0)
    compared = np.append(compared, new_cols, axis=1)
    compared[sec_arr_rows+1:,:] = np.nan 
    compared[:,sec_arr_cols:] = np.nan
```

Is there a simpler, more efficient way in Python to achieve this?

Comment: you can use `np.where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution assuming the first array is always bigger than the second (see comments for general solution, e.g for the second array is bigger on some dimension)

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(18).reshape(6, 3)  # 6x3 array
b = np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2)  # 2x2 array

# create a resulting array of `nan` values
# in general case, desired shape is 
# np.max([a.shape, b.shape], axis=0)
result = np.full(a.shape, np.nan)

# our selection have a shape of the smaller array
# in general case:
# tuple(map(slice, np.min([a.shape, b.shape], axis=0)))
selection = (slice(b.shape[0]), slice(b.shape[1]))

# compare values according the selection
result[selection] = a[selection] == b[selection]
```

Comment: Thank you, Alexander. Appreciate your help.